# asp:DropDownList bootstrap style - always too tall w/o border?

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

**Scenario :**

- I cannot make my **asp:DropDownList** style correctly.
- It works perfectly but it doesn't match the rest of the form.  
  Specifically, the rest of the form has a smaller footprint, no background, and a border.

**Todo :**

- We want dropdowns with a border and white background (like those found on bootstraps form page) (I am sorry - I can't post images yet).

**Tried Case :**

To debug, I made a naked page with only a dropdown and a text box to compare to.  Here is that code:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="col-5">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="notmuch0" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" CssClass="form-control-sm" runat="server"><asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </form>

               <!-- Javascript-->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

    <script src="js/core.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

When we run the code, it creates the following mess for the drop down:

```html
<div class="col-5">
            <input name="notmuch0" type="text" id="notmuch0" class="form-control">
            <select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1" class="form-control-sm select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
 <option value="1">1</option>

</select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--bootstrap select2-container--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 48px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-DropDownList1-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-DropDownList1-container" title="1">1</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
        </div>
```

- And it looks the wrong way still (no border, still a background)
- I have tried working with the bootstrap selectpicker - but it seems that .net ignores EVERYTHING we do to change the class.

**I have about 4 hours of research into this** - and still nothing 
Can you help please?  Will try anything.

 Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: does the output HTML markup show bootstrap loaded (in the styles)? do you have the js files in the specified directory?

Comment: Yes, it is loaded as a resource (all of them are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove jquery-ui.
Only use bootstrap.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the jquery UI doesn't help at all.

Comment: After your thought - I really played with the includes.  Turns out that the jquery-core after my script.js include fixes it but breaks everything else - that made me examine script.js and there it was:

Comment: if (plugins.selectFilter.length) {
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < plugins.selectFilter.length; i++) {
        var select = $(plugins.selectFilter[i]);

        select.select2({
          theme: "bootstrap"
        }).next().addClass(select.attr("class").match(/(input-sm)|(input-lg)|($)/i).toString().replace(new RegExp(",", 'g'), " "));
      }
    }